# SELECT * will not work with table containing geodata

Tags: sql, oracle-spatial, php

The following will not run... I get ***ORA-00932*** error every time..

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM app.table_1';
```

however, this will work (specifying a column name, i.e. `objectid`):

```
$sql = 'SELECT objectid FROM app.table_1';
```

Seeing as I have a table with ~100 columns I do not want to manually hardcode out a list of the columns for this query.. anybody experience this?

legacy question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63562690/cant-select-ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expected-char-got-adt

Comment: So the error occur when you try to get all the columns for every row.  But you can select a single column for all rows: `SELECT objectid FROM app.table_1`.  Have you tried selecting all the columns for a single row? something like: `SELECT * FROM app.table_1 WHERE objectid =1`.  Might help to determine the source of the error - whether its something to do with a column datatype or if its just a bad value (or two..)

Comment: What language environment are you using to run this sql ? The spatial type (SDO_GEOMETRY) is an object type. This is what the SELECT returns and your application code must be able to handle it. It appears that your language environment converts all returned columns to strings which does not happen automatically with objects. If you do not need the spatial column in your application, just do not fetch it.

Comment: Clearly, not fetching that column means building a list of 100 columns. That seems a lot. What does the table contain ? Generally you only fetch strictly those columns your application needs to work on. Does it process them all ?

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind I am simply trying to output the table data to a downloadable .csv file for analysis. I believe it is a data type error; I do have spatial type data.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind also I tried hard coding all 100 rows; I got the same error ... must be an unacceptable column...

Comment: When I said listing all columns I should have clarified: all but the spatial type. Clearly the language you are using is unable to handle object-type columns.

Comment: The one option I can think of is to serialize the géométries in the spatial type to one of the textual notations: WKT, GML, GeoJSON. Which one to use depends on what the output will be used for. Also those are all returned as CLOB: you need verify that the language you use is able to handle those.

Comment: Check out the `SDO_UTIL` PL/SQL package. It has functions `TO_xxxGEOMETRY` for that purpose, where xxx is WKT, GML, KML ... Or `TO_GEOJSON`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say your table contains geodata, I am going to assume you mean it has one or several columns of type SDO_GEOMETRY (Oracle's native geospatial type).

The spatial type (SDO_GEOMETRY) is an object type that internally contains all the information needed to describe a geospatial shape: its type, its coordinate system, its structure and all the coordinates that form the shape.

So, the SELECT statement returns an object type, and your application code must be ready to handle it. It appears that your language environment requests the geospatial object to be returned as a string. But no automatic mapping of the geospatial object to string, ands you get the `ORA-00932` error. Your application expects a string (CHAR) but got an object (ADT or Abstract Data Type).

A possible solution is simply **not** to select the object columns, if your application does not do anything with them.

The other solution is to explicitly serialize the objects to one of the industry-standard string notations for geospatial data. For that you can use functions from the `SDO_UTIL` package:

- **WKT (Well-Known Text):** This is a very old text format, but still very common in GIS. Use `SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY()` to produce it.
- **GML (Geographic Markup Language):** an XML specialization for geospatial data. Use `SDO_UTIL.TO_GMLGEOMETRY()` to produce it.
- **GeoJSON:** a JSON specialization for geospatial data. More modern and adopted by the newer GIS APIs and tools. Use `SDO_UTIL.TO_GEOJSON()` to produce it.

All three functions generate string output. But watch out: the output is a `CLOB` so your language environment must be able to use those. And a geospatial object *can* be large: thousands of points, 10's of thousands, hundreds of thousands ... depending on the nature of the geospatial data you manage.

There is one more possibility, if your geospatial objects are **points**. Points only have one pair of x,y coordinates (or a triple x,y,z if you have 3D data). In this case, you can just extract X and Y (and Z) from the geospatial objects, like this:

```
select ... g.geom.sdo_point.x as x, g.geom.sdo_point.y as y, ...
from geospatial_table g
```

This assumes the geospatial column is called `geom`. But the **important point** here is to **USE AN ALIAS** (here **g**). It is required for the SQL parser to correctly extract the content of the object type.

One more possibility is then to define a view with the above syntax (the `SDO_UTIL` function of the X/Y extraction). This then allows you to use `SELECT *` in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the help @AlbertGodfrind !